# How to get all Redis Pub/Sub channels using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I want to find out what are all the avaliable channels (and subscribers) in Redis Pub/Sub.

I want to do it so I could build a ui to display the current pub/sub status.

From looking on the redis and ioredis packages I couldn't find anything...

Any ideas will be helpful,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `redis` client exposes all Redis commands, including [`PUBSUB CHANNELS`](https://redis.io/commands/pubsub#pubsub-channels-pattern):

```
client.pubsub('channels', (err, channels) => {
  if (err) {
    ...
  } else {
    console.log('Channels:', channels); // array
  }
});
```

I don't think it exposes the subscribers, but you can call [`PUBSUB NUMSUB`](https://redis.io/commands/pubsub#codepubsub-numsub-channel-1--channel-ncode) in a similar way to retrieve the number of subscribers for each channel.

Comment: What is this `redis` client? Which library does it uses?

Comment: @AsmaRahimAliJafri https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis